# Sorting an array - Always having one item at the top?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that goes something like this:

```
$sub = array(
   'add' => 'Add New',
   'default' => 'Home Page',
   'remove' => 'Remove Old'
);
```

This is being built elsewhere, but it does it alphabetically.  Is there anyway to easily sort this so default is always on top?

Comment: [`uksort()`](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you are after sorting

```
$sub = array(
   'add' => 'Add New',
   'default' => 'Home Page',
   'remove' => 'Remove Old'
);
$default = array('default' => $sub['default']);

unset($sub['default']);
$sub = $default + $sub;
print_r($sub);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$sub = array(
   'add' => 'Add New',
   'default' => 'Home Page',
   'remove' => 'Remove Old'
);

function defaultSort($a, $b){
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a == 'default') ? -1 : 1;
}

uksort($sub, 'defaultSort');

var_dump($sub);
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove it then add it again

```
$v = $sub['default'];
unset($sub['default']);
$sub['default'] = $v;
```

Comment: chris, how this makes it **on top** as you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

```
$default = $sub['default'];
unset($sub['default']);
$sub = array_reverse($sub);
$sub['default'] = $default;
$sub = array_reverse($sub);
```

Answer (score 1):

[uksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) should be what you are after

Comment: `usort()` is based on values, `uksort()` is based on keys, which is what OP is after.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to sort - its already sorted. just move the element you want.

```
$tmp = array('default' => $sub['default']) ;
unset( $sub['default']) ;
array_unshift($sub, $tmp);
```